# How can I change the style of an element based on the bound data in WP8 XAML?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

How do you change the styling (say, `Foreground` colour) of an item in a `LongListSelector` based on the databound data on Windows Phone 8?

I'm a XAML noob and I've done a bit of Googling most of which talks about using Triggers but it appears they aren't available in WP8.

For example, if I bind a `List<FooItem>` to my `LongListSelector` where `FooItem`:

```
class FooItem
{
    public string LineOne { get; set; }

    public FooItemStatus Status { get; set; }
}

public enum FooItemStatus
{
    NotSet,
    High,
    Medium,
    Low
}
```

... how would I change the `Foreground` colour to red for items who's `Status == High`?

Comment: Nah ya just need the mvvmlight libs, you'd probably find [this](http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.nl/2013/04/viewmodel-driven-multi-state-animations.html) worth a quick a read to make life easier.

Comment: @ChrisW. thanks for the link but it doesn't really address my problem, at least not in a way that's understandable to the uninitiated. Do you have any more specific examples?

Comment: For the datatrigger side

Answer (score 0):

Bind the Foreground property using a Converter:

```
Foreground="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource FooItemStatusConverter}}"
```

Create a Converter class that maps states to appropriate `Brushes`. Use this class as an e.g. Page/App resource with `FooItemStatusConverter` key.